# Handling inverse foreign keys in hibernate using annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have the following DDL:

```
create table table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,description VARCHAR(50));

create table table2(
  id INTEGER ,
  info VARCHAR(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table1(id)
)
```

And the following java classes:

```
  @Entity
  public class Table1{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Integer id;
  String description;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   Table2 table2;
  }


@Entity
public class Table2{
@Id
Integer id;
String description;
}
```

This is a rough representation of the scenario I am having. I am getting errors like:(this happens during JPA save)

> ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

What is the best way to approach this jpa save operation. Is there anyway to inverse the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Declare Table1 in Table2 and then in the first one use "mappedBy"

Comment: Still not able to avoid run time errors.

Comment: Please post the code that actually persists the entities